# Omitting params in rake task call

Tags: ruby, rake

Lets say I have a rake task

```
task :aa, [:pp1, :pp2, :pp3] do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(:pp2 => "fff")
  puts args.pp1
  puts args.pp2
  puts args.pp3
end
```

How do I pass to rake only 1st and 3rd param, taking the second one from defaults? Object of what type is a thing in square brackets in "rake aa[1,2,3]" call?

Comment: Using a hash as parameter maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using old rake syntax for passing params

```
rake aa pp1=1 pp3=vvv
```

Thus, pp1 and pp3 are available with ENV. Then I replace defaults in args, if I find a param with the same name, which is passed via CLI.

```
args.to_hash.each_key { |k| args.to_hash[k] = ENV[k.to_s] if ENV.has_key?(k.to_s) }
```

After that, I can get any param with nice args.param syntax.

Comment: Does it work? When I try your rake call with your task definition, your parameters pp1 and pp3 are empty, only pp2 get its default value. To get pp1 and pp3 you must analyze `ARGV`.

Comment: Yep, when you pass params via CLI, they are put into ENV. It's TaskArguments lookup method, which fetches the param from ENV, when it can't find it in the internal @hash. So, I've updated the answer with what I really do now.

Answer (score 0):

You could define an additional task (in my example `aa2`) with the parameters (and sequence) you want. The parameter are forwarded to the prerequisites, if they have the same names.

```
require 'rake'

task :aa, [:pp1, :pp2, :pp3] do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(:pp2 => "fff")
  puts args.pp1
  puts args.pp2
  puts args.pp3
end

task :aa2, [:pp1, :pp3] => :aa
```

Call it with:

```
rake aa2[1,3]
```